# Chainable dynamic attributes in Python

Tags: python

I want to both create and set the value of an attribute's attribute in Python.

Here is an example:

```
book = Dynamic()
book.chapter1.section2 = 'abc'
```

My book object does not have a chapter1 attribute so it must be created when **setattr** is called.  I've gotten this to work:

```
book = Dynamic()
book.chapter1 = SubDynamic()
book.chapter1.section2 = 'section 2'
```

I cannot however, figure out how to join it into one line without getting an error telling me that chapter1 does not exist.

Here is what I've got.

```
class Dynamic(object):
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
                sn = SubDynamic(value)
                self.__dict__[name] = v

class SubDynamic(object):
        def __init__(self, attr):
                value = ""
                self.attr = value

        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
                self.__dict__[name] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
        book = Dynamic()
        book.chapter1.section2 = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simplify this a bit by just implementing `__getattr__`:

```
class Dynamic(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        sub = Dynamic()
        setattr(self, name, sub)
        return sub


>>> book = Dynamic()
>>> book.chapter1.section2 = 'abc'
>>> book.chapter1
<test.Dynamic object at 0x7feb0f697910>
>>> book.chapter1.section2
'abc'
```

Comment: Simpler than I could have thought  - I will just further explain (for other reders/the O.P.) that __getattrr__ is just called when an attribute does not exist in the instance. Therefore, further reads of the dynamically created attribute, or other attributes won't cause it to be destroyed by this method. (Check the python docs for `__getattribute__` to control every attribute access instead)